# `bundle: command not found` in systemd script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, bundler, systemd

I'm trying to run a rails server using the below systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=vue-chat-app
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/vue-chat-app.lizardgizzards.com/vue-chat-app/backend-rails/
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec rails s -e production -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3010'
TimeoutSec=60s
RestartSec=30s
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the output I get from `journalctl -xe`

```
Sep 16 16:11:28 lab sudo[27454]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/6 ; PWD=/var/www/vue-chat-app.lizardgizzards.com/vue-chat-app/backend-rails ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/vi /etc/systemd/system/vue-chat-app.service
Sep 16 16:11:28 lab sudo[27454]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Sep 16 16:11:46 lab sudo[27454]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab systemd[1]: vue-chat-app.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab systemd[1]: vue-chat-app.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 69.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit vue-chat-app.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab systemd[1]: Stopped vue-chat-app.
-- Subject: Unit vue-chat-app.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit vue-chat-app.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab systemd[1]: Started vue-chat-app.
-- Subject: Unit vue-chat-app.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit vue-chat-app.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab bash[27526]: /bin/bash: bundle: command not found
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab systemd[1]: vue-chat-app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Sep 16 16:11:56 lab systemd[1]: vue-chat-app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I can run the command `/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec rails s -e production -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3010'` just fine in my terminal, as the user `ubuntu`, but for some reason it isn't running as a systemd script.

Comment: In unit files, you should always use the full path to the command.

Comment: Ooooh... gotcha.